# Join Values with Pipe Character in JS

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to glue some values together using the pipe `|` character but can't seem to work out why this isn't working:

```
vals = vals.join('|');
window.location.replace('<?php echo home_url('cars'); ?>?type=' + vals);
```

I'm console logging this and can see the output of my values separated by the `|` character in the console log but not in the url.

Is there any way to get around this?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just checked your code and it perfectly worked or me. are you sure your php echo works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the browser encodes the pipe character, there should not be a problem with that, in the backend you get the string with the right character.